# render HTML with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have an user favorite list and I want the user to use AJAX to navigate through it.

For now my AJAX function returns a list of dictionaries of the products characteristics.

This is my AJAX:

```
$(".nav_button_2").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();      
    var page = $(this).val();                   
    var url = '/register/account/';   
    $.ajax({        
        url: url,        
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            'page': page,            
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(resp) {
            $('#fav_list').html('')            
            var resp = JSON.parse(resp);            
            $.each(resp, function(i, val) {
            $('#fav_list').append('<h2>' + val.or_name + '</h2>')       
            });                  
        }  
    }); 
});
```

This is $('#fav_list') html:

```
div class='row d-flex justify-content-between'>

      <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 49%;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-2 my-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:auto; height:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px; "
              src="{{ saved.original_product.picture }}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'finder:detail' saved.original_product.id %}"
                  class="aaccount">{{ saved.original_product.real_name }}/ {{ saved.original_product.real_brand }}</a>
              </h5>
              <img src="/static/finder/img/nutriscore-{{ saved.original_product.nutrition_grade}}.svg"
                style="width:70px;"><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 49%;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-2 my-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block " style="width:auto; height:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px; "
              src="{{ saved.sub_product.picture }}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'finder:detail' saved.sub_product.id %}"
                  class="aaccount">{{ saved.sub_product.real_name}}/ {{ saved.sub_product.real_brand }}</a>
              </h5>
              <img src="/static/finder/img/nutriscore-{{ saved.sub_product.nutrition_grade}}.svg"
                style="width:70px;"><br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1 my-auto mx-auto">

          <button type ='button' class=' btn substitut' value='{{ saved.id }}'>{% csrf_token %}<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>              

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It does append `val.or_name` to $('#fav_list')  but what I want is the whole `#fav_list` to be refreshed with an hmtl file. 
I have tried `$('#fav_list').load('nav')` , `nav` being an url in Django pointing to a view rendering an html file.
It worked as well but there is no way I could pass the data I get from AJAX , `val.or_name` for exemple, to the html file.
So I am struggling to get my datas from AJAX to get into the double curly braced one in my html.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're asking how to render each `val` as a full `<div class="card mb-3" style="width: 49%;">`? You should be able to use standard django template rendering (including a loop) for this to create the full HTML content. I.e. right now, the `/register/account/` is sending back a JSON array; just have it render HTML instead

Comment: Yes, that what I want to do but the problem is that I don't know how to send each `val`  (dictionaries) from my AJAX to the view rendering the html file.

Comment: I don't understand what I should do and how the datas will be passed into my template.  What is the difference if HTML is sent back instead of JSON?

Comment: If HTML is sent back you can call `$('#fav_list').html(resp);` and you're done. So now make `/register/account/` render a view instead of printing JSON, and in the view, use [`{% for product in products %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) etc to render the HTML cards.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not quiet sure what you try to accomplish but there are basically two options you can go with:

1.) You refresh your html frontend asynchronously using Ajax to call the `view` and use the newly returned data to your frontend without having an entire page refresh. So Ajax offers you basically the option to just refresh/manipulate parts of the already rendered page.

2.) Call a `view` synrchonously without using Ajax to redirect/render an entire new html page

Depending on the use-case, both have their advantages as well as their disadvantages obviously.

Since you are already using option 1 it seems you want to have an entire new html object rendered upon user click, which basically doesn't need the AJAX logic.

If you can give some more information on the desired outcome I can provide a more detailed and sophisticated input. Also have a look into server- and clientside web development (where Django is a very powerful bridge to use indeed).

[server / client-side web development](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/serverless/glossary/client-side-vs-server-side/)